# Undefined function 'avg' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, cell

I keep getting this error when inputting this code. Im trying to eventually convert a color image to greyscale using nested for loops. Heres the error message "Undefined function 'avg' for input arguments of type 'double'"

```
x = imread('RickMoranis.jpg');
r = size(x, 1);
c = size(x, 2);

 for row = 1:r 
    for col = 1:c 
       y= mean(avg(row,col,:));
    end
end
end
```

Comment: I don't think `avg` is a matlab function, do you mean `mean`? (The error is saying it doesn't know what the function `avg` is)

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in function `avg`.

Most likely, you wanted to write

```
y= mean(x(row,col,:));
```

Note that instead of the double loop, you can also write

```
y = mean(x,3);
```

Finally, if you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you way want to check out `rgb2gray` for conversion of RGB to grayscale.

Comment: +1 for teaching some basic vectorization as well as answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting avg to calculate the average, use mean. It seems you already have the command mean in your code. There is no built-in function avg in matlab.